# How to display data on Gridview in ASP.NET 4.0 when we click button?

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net

```
Imports System.Data.Odbc
Imports System.Data
Partial Class VIEW_SALARY_DETAILS
     Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

   Protected Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Dim cons, query As String
    Dim con As OdbcConnection
    Dim adpt As OdbcDataAdapter
    cons = "dsn=Courier; UID=Courier; PWD=123;"
    con = New OdbcConnection(cons)
    con.Open()
    query = "select * from EMPLOYEE"
    Dim ds As DataSet
    adpt = New OdbcDataAdapter(query, con)
    ds = New DataSet
    adpt.Fill(ds, "Courier")
    GridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables()
    con.Close()
   End Sub
End Class
```

I wrote the above code but it does not display data.
Same thing is possible in VB.NET application.
How do we do it for ASP.net 4.0?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to call the `DataBind()` method. Try this

```
DataSet ds= new DataSet();    
GridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables();
GridView1.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 0):

You missed a line after

```
GridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0]   //do some correction here..

GridView1.DataBind();        // add this line
```

You need to bind the GridView with the Datasource..

Your code will be

```
Imports System.Data.Odbc
Imports System.Data
Partial Class VIEW_SALARY_DETAILS
     Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

   Protected Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Dim cons, query As String
    Dim con As OdbcConnection
    Dim adpt As OdbcDataAdapter
    cons = "dsn=Courier; UID=Courier; PWD=123;"
    con = New OdbcConnection(cons)
    con.Open()
    query = "select * from EMPLOYEE"
    Dim ds As DataSet
    adpt = New OdbcDataAdapter(query, con)
    ds = New DataSet
    adpt.Fill(ds, "Courier")
    GridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0]
    GridView1.DataBind()
    con.Close()
   End Sub
End Class
```

Ensure that connection or sql string you used should be correct.

Comment: above database connection is correct.....I am become able to insert values into database using above type of connection .... but unable displaying whole table data into gridview......

Comment: "DataKeyNames must be specified for persisted selection to work." This error occured

Comment: Why you have set persistant selection property to true.Remove Old GridView First don't know what you have done.. Take a new GridView from Toolbox. select autogenerated column property true. hope this will be running fine.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest this:

Assuming this markup:

[image]

So we dragged in a button , and a gridview.

Now, double click on the button, and we get/have this code stub:

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient

Public Class HotelGrid
Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

End Sub


Sub LoadGrid()

    Using cmdSQL As New SqlCommand("SELECT ID, FirstName, LastName, HotelName, City from tblHotels",
                    New SqlConnection(My.Settings.TEST3))

        cmdSQL.Connection.Open()
        GridView1.DataSource = cmdSQL.ExecuteReader
        GridView1.DataBind()

    End Using

End Sub

Protected Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    LoadGrid()

End Sub


End Class
```

Note a FEW important things here.

First I VERY much recommend for general sql data pulls, use the sql command object.

Why?

Well, the command object has:

```
A place to hold/have/set the sql (sql command text)
A connection object - no need to create a separate one
A data reader - no need to create a separate one
```

In other words, the sql command object HAS ALL THREE basic bits and parts to pull data.

And we often want say some kind of recordset (data table), so we COULD have done this:

```
   dim MyTable as new DataTable
    Using cmdSQL As New SqlCommand("SELECT ID, FirstName, LastName, HotelName, City from tblHotels",
                    New SqlConnection(My.Settings.TEST3))

        cmdSQL.Connection.Open()
        MyTable.load(cmdSQL.ExecuteReader)

        GridView1.DataSource = MyTable
        GridView1.DataBind()

    End Using
```

So note how in above, we created a data table object. And that data table can then be interated with for/each. You can even edit data in that table, or as above shows, load up the data table with data - and THEN assign it to the grid view.

The resulting output is thus this:

[image]

FYI:
In my example, I used sqlclient provider. In YOUR case, you are using ODBC provider. So the above code will be exact same, but NOW using ODBC, we get this:

So in place of ado.net (sql Client), you using ODBC. So you have a

```
Imports System.Data.Odbc
```

And thus our load grid code could/would be this:

```
Sub LoadGrid2()

    Using cmdSQL As New OdbcCommand("SELECT ID, FirstName, LastName, HotelName, City from tblHotels",
                    New OdbcConnection(My.Settings.TEST3ODBC))

        cmdSQL.Connection.Open()
        GridView1.DataSource = cmdSQL.ExecuteReader
        GridView1.DataBind()

    End Using

End Sub
```

So, note how the code is really the "same", but JUST with a different provider (ODBC in your case).

And you can still declare and use say a "data table" to hold the query results.